# Normalize List of maps into Map of sublists

Tags: list, groovy, maps

How can this be reversed in groovy?

ie.

I want to turn this:

[ [a:"c", b:"e"], [a:"d",b:"f"] ]    -- can have more elements in the list

into: [a: ["c","d"], b: ["e","f"]]

Answer (score 0):

So, we can:

Melt the list of maps into a long list where each element has a common k/v structure

Then group by the key

Then we need to go through this new map, and clean up the values

That gets us:

```
def result = [ [a:"c", b:"e"], [a:"d",b:"f"] ]
    *.collect { [k: it.key, v: it.value] } 
    .flatten()
    .groupBy { it.k }
    .collectEntries { a, b ->
        [a, b.v]
    }

assert result ==​ [a:['c', 'd'], b:['e', 'f']]​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! it is exactly what I needed.